# mariadb - Table XXX doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mariadb

So after ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN  I realized it should be a decimal() not int(). Adding the column was supper fast. When I did a ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN (big mistake, should have used gh-ost) I knew it would be trouble since the table is pretty huge about 50GB and it is partitioned (one per month). Anyway I lefts it running and then when I came back the terminal must have timed out and the process failed. The table is still there in "show tables" but on select it says  it does not exist in engine. The ibd files are in the datadir

[image]

```
select * from SPX_21;
```

> ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'cellpage_MRA.SPX_21' doesn't exist in engine

ls of the datadir shows:

[image]

the error log shows basically now there is a discrepancy between Innodb engine and mariadb

> 2021-05-01 19:25:58 24 [Warning] InnoDB: Table cellpage_MRA/SPX_21#P#p0 contains 5 user defined columns in InnoDB, but 6 columns in MariaDB. Please check INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS and https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.

The link does not really help at all.

Is there a way to somehow re-sync the ibd data to mariadb table?

The show table status simply shows the table name is there but everything else about that table is null

```
show table status where Name like '%SPX_21%'
```

[image]

However the info schema shows all is well???? or is defined as it should...

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLES 
WHERE NAME LIKE '%SPX_21%';
```

[image]

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_ID>=60244 and TABLE_ID<=60253;
```

[image: For All partitions]

Column definitions show 5 columns for ALL partitions in schema

Any help would be great.

Thanks

A possible solution.
https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/04/22/how-to-recover-table-structure-from-innodb-dictionary/